# SQL Statement to find next move

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, report

I currently have a situation where I have to find the next value after my current move.

Currently I have below:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(17), PlannedStartDateUTC,13) 
 FROM   VisitMovement VM 
 WHERE  vm.VisitMovement_GUID = (SELECT VM2.VisitMovement_GUID 
                                 FROM VisitMovement VM2 
                                 WHERE vm2.OrderIndex = (VisitMovement.OrderIndex +10) 
                                   AND VM2.Visit_GUID = VisitMovement.Visit_GUID )) AS [Estimated Move],
```

Which works by using `VisitMovement.OrderIndex` to find the next move. However, in some situations the `OrderIndex` might not be +10 but +20.

I can't understand how I would logically write this to find the next move.

Any more information please get in touch.

Comment: Not clear what you need.   That SQL does not even have matching ( )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY OrderIndex` to find the next:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(17), PlannedStartDateUTC,13) 
 FROM   VisitMovement VM 
 WHERE  vm.VisitMovement_GUID = 
        ( 
               SELECT TOP 1 VM2.VisitMovement_GUID 
               FROM   VisitMovement VM2 
               WHERE  VM2.Visit_GUID = VisitMovement.Visit_GUID 
               ORDER BY VM2.OrderIndex) AS [Estimated Move],
```

Comment: Hello Tim,This will just found the top plannedstartdate and not the next. Any ideas on finding the next?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(17), PLANNEDSTARTDATEUTC,13) 
 FROM   VISITMOVEMENT VM 
 CROSS APPLY
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 VM2.* 
                    FROM VISITMOVEMENT VM2 
                    WHERE   VM2.VISIT_GUID = VM.VISIT_GUID
                            AND VM.ORDERINDEX < VM2.ORDERINDEX
                    ORDER BY VM2.ORDERINDEX ASC
                ) [ESTIMATED MOVE]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Tim's code just needs a little tweak (pseudo code as no examples supplied):

```
 SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(17), PlannedStartDateUTC,13) 
 FROM   VisitMovement VM 
 WHERE  vm.VisitMovement_GUID = 
    ( 
           SELECT TOP 1 VM2.VisitMovement_GUID 
           FROM   VisitMovement VM2 
           WHERE  VM2.Visit_GUID = VisitMovement.Visit_GUID 
           AND    VM2.OrderIndex > VM.OrderIndex
           ORDER BY VM2.OrderIndex
    ) AS [Estimated Move]
```

However, I don't know what version of SQL you are on, but have you considered the LEAD syntax?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx

Something like

```
SELECT
LEAD(PlannedStartDateUTC,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Visit_GUID ORDER BY OrderIndex)
FROM VisitMovement;
```